# Chrome browser window opens and closes immediately with an error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, jmeter

I am running the below Jmeter sampler. It loads and launches the webpage but immediately exits/closes with an error message.

### Sampler Code (Java Script):

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()

var pk = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium, org.openqa.selenium.support.ui)

WDS.browser.get('http://google.com')

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

### Error message:

> JmeterTestCase
>   Creating summariser  Created the tree successfully using
>   C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\IMT4.0PerformanceNEW.jmx Starting the test @
>   Tue Jan 31 17:44:28 GMT+05:30 2017 (1485864868015) Waiting for
>   possible shutdown message on port 4445 Starting ChromeDriver
>   (v2.9.248315) on port 34337 Jan 31, 2017 5:44:39 PM
>   org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder
>   INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2).
>   org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@32fa8f3c

### Versions used:

Jmeter - apache-jmeter-2.13

selenium 2.46.0

Browsers- Chrome 43.0 / Mozilla

I tried a lot but no luck. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: 2.46.0 is quiet an old version, try to update to newer one http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: Thanks . Its resolved now, it was an issue with the code where it was waiting for nothing and hence it was exiting after the completion of test case. The error I pasted above is just info message has nothing do with the closing the browser .